# PHP File Download with ajax Problems

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, upload

i am this problem of not being able to download image from server to my PC(No saving prompt ) , no error message have been shown

The output i am receiving is some unreadable code from the google chrome inspect element

Thanks in advance

Javascript

```
function Download(id) {

            console.log(id);

             $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'DownloadRequest.php',
              data: {filename: id.trim()},
            });


 }
```

DownloadRequest.php File

```
<?php

    $file = $_POST['filename'];

    header ("Content-Type: application/download");
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize("$file"));
    $fp = fopen("$file", "r");
    fpassthru($fp);
?>
```

Solution

```
function Download(id) {
    window.location="DownloadRequest.php?url="+id.trim();
 }

<?php

$file = $_GET['url'];;

header ("Content-Type: application/download");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize("$file"));
$fp = fopen("$file", "r");
fpassthru($fp);
```

?>

Comment: See this post for a download using jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this, instead of using ajax,

```
window.location="DownloadRequest.php?filename";
```

Final code,

```
function Download(id) {
   console.log(id);
   window.location="DownloadRequest.php?filename";
}
```

Comment: what else you want to do with that??

Comment: check the edit.. you have to pass the file name, use `$_GET` and write code to download that.

Comment: Sorry is my fault for not editing the code Properly its working thanks for the help

Comment: Yup Thanks for the Help

Comment: Glad i could help you:)